# Error in styles.xml

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, styles

I've placed a styles.xml file in res/values folder and it gives me this error.

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget'.

Here is my code;

```
<resources>
<style name="Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@+android:drawable/bar1</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@+ndroid:drawable/bar2</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@+android:drawable/scroll1</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">8px</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
</style>
```

the error occurs on the line == style name="Widget.SeekBar"

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its shold be like this you need parent Widget than you can put child of it. needed first.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Widget"></style><style name="Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/bar1</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/bar2</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@+android:drawable/scroll1</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">8px</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: also that @+android:drawable/scroll1 change it with proper drawable syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@+ndroid:drawable/bar2</item>
```

should read

```
<item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@+android:drawable/bar2</item>
```

Comment: you are right I should read :).. but unfortunately that doesn't fix my problem :/